# xslt avoid duplicate values

Tags: java, xslt

I have incoming xml like:

```
<ROWSET2>
   <ROWSET2_ROW>
      <ID_GROUP>1</ID_GROUP>
      <NAME>A</NAME>
      <GROUP_PRICE>10</GROUP_PRICE>
   </ROWSET2_ROW>   
   <ROWSET2_ROW>
      <ID_GROUP>2</ID_GROUP>
      <NAME>B</NAME>
      <GROUP_PRICE>15</GROUP_PRICE>
   </ROWSET2_ROW> 
   <ROWSET2_ROW>
      <ID_GROUP>2</ID_GROUP>
      <NAME>C</NAME>
      <GROUP_PRICE>15</GROUP_PRICE>
   </ROWSET2_ROW> 
   <ROWSET2_ROW>
      <ID_GROUP>3</ID_GROUP>
      <NAME>D</NAME>
      <GROUP_PRICE>20</GROUP_PRICE>
   </ROWSET2_ROW>   
</ROWSET2>
```

from which i want to print / select

---

### GroupID | Item name | Bundle price

### 1       |    A      |    10

### 2       |    B      |    15

### -    |    C      |    -

### 3       |    D      |    20

i am using xslt 1.0

Comment: Sorry, but what is your expected output? A text with 4 lines, items seperated by pipes? Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is done by [Muenchian](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

Comment: pipes are just for representation.., just don't want to print same group id, only print item name

Comment: basically i don't want to print same groupID and gruop_price.., thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

it did it by "preceding-sibling".

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1]/ID_BUNDLE = ID_BUNDLE">
        <!-- do not print -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- print -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: You did wrong - see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Please suggest right way and mention my mistake... thanks in advance